# How do I get the index of both mesh lines to size them based on index?

Tags: geometry-nodes

so I am trying to make the points on my 2 mesh lines sized by index but the problem is that something weird is happening were one is working but the other is like now exactly how it should be, here are some pictures for better explanation

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your 2 lines share the same index, meaning on line is going from 0 to 9, the other from 10 to 19.

Comment: Alright so how do I fix it, they need to be seperate because I need 2

Comment: You can't. Same object = same unique index. You need some math, for example (index modulo 10), depending on what you want precisely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is an index? An index is simply a unique, ordered integer, starting at $0$ and incrementing by $1$ for each next element.

Imagine that you have a line of 5 prisoners:

[image]

###### <sup>Illustration by Karen B. Jones - [Shutterstock](https://www.shutterstock.com/da/image-illustration/line-prisoners-walk-chains-linking-them-490312426)</sup>

Each point of a mesh line represents one prisoner (and an edge a chain between them). So in your case there's 10 prisoners:

#0#1#2#3#4#5#6#7#8#9

But in another prison there's 10 more prisoners, with same numbers. If the prisons are merged, the numbers will get duplicated:

old prisoners: #0#1#2#3#4#5#6#7#8#9

migrated prisoners: #0#1#2#3#4#5#6#7#8#9

This just won't do! In prison you don't have a name, just a number; so the number better be unique, even if it can get much bigger than a single digit as a result…

[image]

Therefore upon joining <strike>geometries</strike> prisons, the prisoners migrating from one facility to another will be renumbered:

old prisoners: #0#1#2#3#4#5#6#7#8#9

migrated prisoners: #10#11#12#13#14#15#16#17#18#19

This is done automatically in Blender. Perhaps worth to note at this point, the renumbering happens also if you remove a prisoner; so if a prisoner dies, everyone with an index higher than of this prisoner, gets it decreased by 1 (in future some more efficient approaches could be implemented like assigning the now free number to the prisoner with the biggest number). What's important is, there's never either a duplicate or a gap in the indices.

If you don't want such functionality, you can copy the index to a new attribute: it's like asking the guards to read each prisoner's number, and tattoo it on the prisoner's forehead (the analogy is getting more and more macabre…). Now, when the prisoner moves to another prison, he will be given a new number, but the tattoo will stay:

[image]

Sometimes you can get away with a simpler, mathematical approach: for example here, because each prison has the same number of prisoners, you can **»calculate«** the original prisoner number by getting the remainder of dividing by $10$:

[image]

(no visible change in the test is intended)

Comment: I know what an index is, you didn't have to use that whole analogy sir, but thank you gonna try this

Answer (score 4):

The allocation of indices will depend on relative element creation time, there's no guarantee of order, so there's lots of potential for hidden bugs, using them. That aside, on a set of mesh lines, you can at least ensure indices are sequential-per-line, by converting to curves and back again:

[image]

Accumulating a simple value of  `1` on points, by Mesh island, 'Leading', gives you an index-sequence per line, starting at 1. If you want to start at 0, use 'Trailing'. (The example input Geometry, here, is a set of lines)

The group can be used to scale points:

[image]

Thus:

[image]